# Cognos Drill Through Report Issue With Boolean Variable

Tags: cognos, cognos-10, cognos-bi

I'm running a drill though report on multiple pages. Page1 contains the source report. A target report is on Page2. I want the target report page to only render when a specific data item value is selected in the source report.

Normally a Boolean value like this "ParamDisplayValue('Service Task Description') is not null", would work fine but I want it to be more specific than "is not null" because I am going to add more target reports running from specific data items in the same source report column.

I tried a Boolean value, [Service Tasks].[Service Task Description] = 'General Service Item' but it gives me an error when I select 'General Service Item' in the source report.

I also tried a Boolean value "ParamDisplayValue('Service Task Description') = 'General Service Item'. This does not give me an error but it will say "No data to retrieve" because I am now passing the parameter value and not the data item value.

I wish I could have the option in the drill through definition to pass both parameter and data item value at the same time but I can only choose one or the other.